# Регулярные выражения в другой кодировке

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь найти все ╤В╨Р╨ в тексте, вот мое регулярное выражение:

```
arr = re.findall(r"╤В╨Р╨", text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

на выходе массив пустой
`cat text | grep ╤В╨Р╨` находит нужные строки, т.е. в файле они есть. Как можно изменить регулярное выражение для поиска в другой кодировке?

Comment: Вообще-то если данные брать со строки все работает. А данные в text вы откуда берете? Как вариант приведите пример части входных данных.

Comment: Кодировка для текста используется для сохранения текста на жёсткий диск, или для передачи по сети. А регулярки работают с текстовыми объектами в памяти, и к этим объектам не применимо понятие кодировки, так как они не бывают закодированы. Перед применением регулярки текст нужно раскодировать, кодировка должна быть правильной, и поиск уже производить в не закодированном тексте.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = re.findall(r"╤В╨Р╨".encode("utf-8").decode("unicode_escape"),
    text.encode("utf-8").decode("unicode_escape"), flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]